# cURL zip file is not a valid archive

Tags: bash, zip, curl, git-bash

I wrote a script to download a zip file based on some user inputs. The file downloads but cannot be opened by a zip file extractor. Git Bash on Win 10.

```
curl -u user:pwd -k -# -C - "$REQUEST_URL" -o "$DIR"
```

When I download the same file via browser I see that the file is smaller and is a valid zip file.

I understand the -o parameter is supposed to get the file in binary format and save with the name I give it.

Is there another parameter I need to use? I do not have wget btw.

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `-o "$DIR".ZIP`, for instance?

Comment: "$DIR" contains the path and filename the zip file is saved into. somedir/zipfile.zip.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the -C parameter.
The problem was that the first download was interrupted, and when I re-ran the script it tried to append the remaining bytes and failed to do so correctly.
Now I remove the directory contents where the file is downloaded to, I don't need or want this feature, so I will remove it.